# Is there a drink that's analogous to coffee but made with cocoa beans?

Tags: coffee, cocoa

Is there a drink out there that is made identically to coffee except with cocoa beans?

I would be interested in finding either a drink with the exact roasting process or a drink brewed with ground cocoa beans. I've heard of something called "choffee" - how does that fit in?

Comment: I've tried to write an answer, but honestly it's a bit difficult because I'm not really sure exactly what you're trying to find out. You might consider posting questions explicitly asking about how cacao beans or coffee beans are processed if you want to know more about that.

Comment: Choffee (choffy) is exactly what you're asking about.  It's brewed the same as coffee but it roasts and grinds the cacao bean.  I've bought it from a company called Crio Bru.  I find it a little bitter on its own, but with a little sweetened creamer (I use hazelnut) it tastes really good.  It doesn't have the thickness that hot or drinking chocolate has.  It's thinner like coffee, but definitely more bitter than hot chocolate.

Comment: What you're asking for is closer to the original Mayan use of the cocoa beans, although they'd mix in other spices (chilies & cinnamon) and sometimes a thickener (cornmeal), and then serve it cold.  I think it was cold brewed, but most accounts don't specifically mention that part of it.  (they do say it was frothed before serving, either by pouring back and forth between two pitchers, or with a molinillo.

Answer (score 5):

You certainly *could* brew a drink from pure cocoa powder. It'll be pretty bitter, though; if you don't like unsweetened chocolate you might not like it much, though. So you'll most likely end up adding dairy and sugar, and ending up with hot cocoa.

It won't ever be exactly the same process though. In both cases there's a lot of processing of the beans, and the details differ. But most importantly, while with coffee you can buy and use whole beans, you wouldn't do that with cacao. Cacao beans contain a large amount of fat, so if you want cocoa powder, part of the processing is separating out cocoa solids (which can become cocoa powder) and cocoa butter. If you don't separate them, you end up with a thick paste called chocolate liquor. So you're never going to see whole roasted cacao beans.

But if you're willing to set aside all those differences, I suppose hot cocoa is analogous to coffee, if that means anything.

Comment: yea if that "beans" anything.

Answer (score 4):

Koko Samoa is a chocolate drink popular in the Pacific. It seems to involve just simmering ground cocoa beans in water and later adding sugar. Most of the online information is people trying to sell it to you - in Samoa people just buy it at roadside stands or make it for themselves. I did manage to find [one article](https://chocolateclass.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/koko-samoa-simple-recipe-complex-history/) that might be interesting for you.

If I had known before visiting Samoa that this existed, I would have been sure to try some, and then I could report to you what it is like.